# Initializing Constant Array of Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, constants

So, what I'm trying to do is initialize an array of vectors holding constant values. In essence, it's this:

```
const std::vector<std::string> MyConstant[] = { {"const1", "const2"}, {"const3", "const4", "const5"} };
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I haven't used vectors very often. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Not much I can say without any kind of problem elaboration.

Comment: It is good in C++11 but not C++03.

Comment: if you're using g++ or clang++, use --std=c++11

Comment: Running fine on [ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/XLmbGp)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a static function to initialize your constant variable, e.g., like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> GenerateMyConstant() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> constants;
    {
        std::vector<std::string> element;
        element.push_back("const1");
        element.push_back("const2");
        constants.push_back(element);
    }
    {
        std::vector<std::string> element;
        element.push_back("const3");
        element.push_back("const4");
        element.push_back("const5");
        constants.push_back(element);
    }
    return std::move(constants);
}
```

Then, you can intialize your constant:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> MyConstant(GenerateMyConstant());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of Visual Studio below 2013 to compile this code, it doesn't work because [the compiler doesn't support initializer lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist).

If you're using a recent version of gcc or clang to compile your code, it should work.

You could use [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/assign/doc/index.html#tutorial) to do it without intitializer lists:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> 

using namespace boost::assign; 

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::string> l = list_of("const1")("const2")("const3")("const4")("const5");
    const std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > MyConstant = list_of(l);

    for (size_t i=0; i<MyConstant.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<MyConstant[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout<<MyConstant[i][j]<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"----"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output [here](http://codepad.org/guJbC3Id)

You could even condense it further:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> 

using namespace boost::assign; 
int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> strvec;
    const std::vector<strvec> MyConstant = 
        list_of (strvec()=(list_of("1")("2")("3")("4")("5")))
                (strvec()=(list_of("a")("b")("c")("d")("e")));

    for (size_t i=0; i<MyConstant.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<MyConstant[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout<<MyConstant[i][j]<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"----"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output [here](http://codepad.org/6dvx0IcS)

Comment: So, how would I do this without using an initializer list?